# How to deal with this 2-norm?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is an $m×n$ matrix, verify the inequality $\|A\|_\infty\leq\sqrt n\|A\|_2$ and give an example of a nonzero matrix if the equality is achieved.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Maybe start with reviewing the definitions of these norms.

Comment: The 2-norm of a matrix is its maximal singular value? How to represent the singular value of A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $0\neq x\in\mathbb R^n$, we have $$\Vert x\Vert_2=\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}\leq \sqrt{n\max_{1\leq j\leq n}x_j^2}=\sqrt{n}\Vert x\Vert_\infty$$ and $$\Vert Ax\Vert_\infty=\max_{1\leq j\leq n}|(Ax)_j|=\sqrt{\max_{1\leq j\leq n}(Ax)_j^2}\leq\sqrt{(Ax)_1^2+\cdots+(Ax)_n^2}=\Vert Ax\Vert_2$$ which gives $$\frac{\Vert Ax\Vert_\infty}{\Vert x\Vert_\infty}\leq\sqrt{n}\frac{\Vert Ax\Vert_2}{\Vert x\Vert_2}$$